# In which case i must reset the stack trace by throw ex?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I read about throw and throw ex and understand the difference.
When i use throw ex reset the stack trace.
Now I have the question why to reset stack trace?In which case I must do this?
Could someone to write a simple example to understand it?

Comment: You never **have** to do it, and usually - if not even allways - it´s bad idea to do this as you´re losing information. You can however wrap your exception into a new one, which may be more approriate.

Comment: Having said this your question will probably become closed, as their is no "right" or "whrong" answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have such a case when you fire some HTTP request, and it indicates you have not authenticated (for example username and password are incorrect). Usually, the entire call stack is irrelevant since it is a controlled exception.

You could create a new exception and just drop the original exception, but personally I would always provide the entire call stack.